# Are Choy Sum and Gai Lan grown in Canada or US?

Tags: vegetables

My grandparents in Toronto fancy buying unmarred Gai Lan and Choy Sum. They tried Loblaws/T&T (same company, so same supplier?), Sunny Supermarket; but their Chinese vegetables are too shoddy. They're yellowish, have black smudges or streaks, or have holes (chewed by bugs?) or bugs themselves.

My grandparents noticed Loblaws/T&T's packaging blazons Mexico as the origin, so 
they fancy seeing if Chinese vegetables grown in Canada-US may be less marred?

Comment: What exactly is your question? If it's the question in the title, "Are choy sum and gai lan grown in Canada or the US" the answer is yes, some people grow them: https://nesfp.org/farmers/rechhat-proum. But that doesn't seem like very useful information. Are you asking where your grandparents could find such produce?

Comment: @Juhasz Are they grown commercially in Canada or US??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes, they are](https://blog.heinens.com/introducing-gai-lan-and-choy-sum-new-asian-vegetables/).

I'd suggest finding a specialty/organic market near you (one like Heinen's), since such places generally have clear labeling on where food was grown.